# IE image border won't go away

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an image with the following CSS:

```
#index-img {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Yet the typical blue IE image border still appears.  It's not a cache issue, as I've cleared it.  Any ideas?  It's kinda annoying.

Comment: Maybe the border is added via `:active` ?

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about IE10 - you have to apply style *inline*:

```
<img id="index-img" src="bla.png" style="border:none" />
```

Applying it via class won't work. IE10 is that peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it helps:

```
#index-img {
    border:none
}
```